# NSAttributedString - Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0) when setup attributedText on iOS 14-

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, simulator

I have some weird problem. On my Macbook M1, when i build my project, everythink working well on physical iPhone XS 14.4 and 8 14.0.1, also on simulator with iOS 14+. But when i run any simulator with older iOS than 14.0 my app crashing when setup attributedText.
Here is my code:

```
        guard let input = input else { return nil }

        guard let data = input.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true) else { return nil  }


        if let string = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil).string
        {
            //Set color and font
            let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white , NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)  ]
            let myAttrString = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: myAttribute)
            return myAttrString
        }

        return nil
    }
```

The crash is in this line:

```
        if let string = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil).string
```

for **NSAttributedString** i got error **Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)**
I have try run my App on Macbook Intel, and there everythink is ok on simulators with older iOS than 14.0. So this is for me weird. Should I throw the application on the App Store anyway, because the fault lies only in the simulator or, however, the users may have a problem?
I tried various solutions from the Internet, I changed the NSAttributedString modifications, but the applications always crash in the same place.

Comment: Why are you converting your string to NSAttributedString and getting the string from it? It doesn't make any sense. Btw you should use `.utf8` when converting your string to data

Comment: @LeoDabus using `NSAttributedString` is the way to convert HTML to `NSString`, AFAIK. Above code is converting `<div>hello world</div>` to a white 17 point attributed string.